# Grabbed/Literal unicode display differently on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, character-encoding

In the following code, I have two unicode. The first is grabbed from a web page which is encoded in GB2312, the second is a literal unicode.

```
logging.debug(type(s))
logging.debug(s)
logging.debug(repr(s))
logging.debug(s.encode('gb2312', errors='replace'))
logging.debug(s.encode('utf-8', errors='replace'))
tmplt = jinja_env.get_template('hello.html')
logging.debug(tmplt.render(text=s))

self.response.out.write(s)
self.response.out.write(repr(s))
self.response.out.write(tmplt.render(text=s))
self.response.out.write('<br>')

s = u'你好'
logging.debug(type(s))
logging.debug(s)
logging.debug(repr(s))
logging.debug(s.encode('gb2312', errors='replace'))
logging.debug(s.encode('utf-8', errors='replace'))
tmplt = jinja_env.get_template('hello.html')
logging.debug(tmplt.render(text=s))

self.response.out.write(s)
self.response.out.write(repr(s))
self.response.out.write(tmplt.render(text=s))
```

However, the gae log shows that only the latter works correctly.

```
<type 'unicode'>
ÂÂ Ã¤Â½Â Ã¥Â¥Â½
u'\xc2\x97\xc2\x8b \xc3\xa4\xc2\xbd\xc2\xa0\xc3\xa5\xc2\xa5\xc2\xbd'
???? ?��??????????
ÂÂ Ã¤Â½Â Ã¥Â¥Â½
ÂÂ Ã¤Â½Â Ã¥Â¥Â½

<type 'unicode'>
你好
u'\u4f60\u597d'
���
你好
你好
```

I've verified the grabbed unicode and the literal unicode are the same in ipython, and the grabbed unicode works fine in my local dev_appserver.

thx @unutbu, the two repr(s) are different on app engine, but the same in my local dev server. I'm using GAE 1.6.1 with python27 runtime. Below is my local dev server log.

```
<type 'unicode'>
你好
u'\u4f60\u597d'
你好
浣犲ソ
锘夸綘濂?
<type 'unicode'>
你好
u'\u4f60\u597d'
你好
浣犲ソ
锘夸綘濂?
```

Could anyone give me a hand?

Comment: But how are you converting the value "grabbed" from the page into unicode in the first place?

Comment: I decoded the bytestring using the 'gb2312' encoding, `response.read().decode(self.ENCODING, errors='replace')`

Comment: Please post `logging.debug(repr(s))`.

Comment: Could you post `repr(response.read())` and the value of `self.ENCODING`?

Comment: @unutbu self.ENCODING is a string 'gb2312', response.read() is fetched through urlfetch service, which is encoded in 'gb2312'

Comment: I don't have an answer, but perhaps if you can trace the evolution of `repr(response.read())` to `repr(s)` (comparing GAE to the local server), you should be able to find where the two are diverging. Looking at the `repr`s is helpful because it gives an unambiguous representation of `str` and `unicode` objects.

Comment: Finally I found the problem. The fetched data is passed to lxml, and it returns the `repr` of the data. It still to be seen why my local dev_server works fine. thx.